# How can I save two entities of the same type in one transaction?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a `OfferRepository extends JpaRepository<OfferEntity, Long>` which, at one point, has to save two entities:

```
@Transactional
public OfferDto save(OfferDto offerDto) {

    // ..

    OfferEntity oneOfferEntity = new OfferEntity();
    // Copy data ..
    oneOfferEntity = this.offerRepository.save(oneOfferEntity);

    // Further down ..

    OfferEntity anotherOfferEntity = new OfferEntity();
    // Copy data ..
    anotherOfferEntity = this.offerRepository.save(anotherOfferEntity);

    return OfferDto.fromEntity(anotherOfferEntity);
}
```

My problem is that it would seem that only the second entity gets stored. The first seems to get ignored - unless I comment out the second save operation.

I never had that situation - is it not possible to do this? How can I make sure that two different entities are getting saved here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can do that, but the problem is that, entities are considered as `same`.So it is the reason you got only the second saved, you can try to do something like this:

```
OfferEntity oneOfferEntity = new OfferEntity();
oneOfferEntity.setProperty1("1");
OfferEntity anotherOfferEntity = new OfferEntity();
anotherOfferEntity.setProperty1("2");
```

Where `Property1` is some property in the entity.

More details: `JPA` or `Hibernate` uses `hashCode()` and `equals()` to decide if the entities are the same, in your case two entities are considered same.